# Is there any bus from Bergamo to Venezia (Italy)?

Tags: public-transport, buses, italy, venice, bergamo

I'm arriving to Bergamo airport next week and I would like to go to Venezia (Venice) as soon as possible. I know there is a train from city center, but it's too expensive (35 € one way) and my experience is that usually buses are cheaper.

Comment: You can also check www.flixbus.com
Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [airport site](http://www.sacbo.it/Editorial/newsCategoryViewProcess.jsp?editorialID=2656&currentMenu=2175) there is nothing that goes directly to Venezia.

There are 2 bus companies that service the Bergamo airport as well [Autostradale](http://www.autostradale.it/) which could get you to Milan or Brescia and then you would have to take the train.  The other one [OrioShuttle](http://www.orioshuttle.com/_eng/le-linee.cfm) will only get you to Milan and then you can take a train or a bus.  But based on what I am reading [here](http://www.italylogue.com/planning-a-trip/getting-from-milan-to-venice.html) it's not preferred and what you save may not be worth it.  But if you still choose to go check out this site: http://www.italybus.it

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the train from Bergamo to Venice. Train station in Venice Santa Lucia is 2.2km far from San Marco square.

Take a look to this: http://www.trenitalia.com/cms/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=ad1ce14114bc9110VgnVCM10000080a3e90aRCRD